# Разработка под андроид (вопрос к желающим)

Tags: android, java

Кто желает разрабатывать в команде андроид-приложения и стартапы под данную платформу? Пишите в данный топик свои мысли, пожелания и прочие соображения.

Желателен опыт, мотивация и чем они выше, тем лучше:) Так будет проще всем!
Условия разные, идеи тоже: OpenSource-проекты, стартапы, платный софт для маркета, аутсорс.
Кто желает вместе развиваться в этом направлении и не просиживать жизнь по 8 часов в офисе ежедневно - пишите!

**UPD**

**Джаббер-комната:** android-devs@conference.jabber.ru

Также возникла идея создать сайт для андроид-сообщества. Пока что времени у меня на это нет, но кто может в этом помочь также пишите мне, обсудим его функционал. Идея сайта - место, где будут себя чувствовать комфортно андроид-разработчики.

Comment: Я рад быть желающим, но только начинаю юзать движок и технологию. Ты мне кстате тут http://hashcode.ru/questions/69726/создание-игр-для-android давал рекомендации)

Comment: дроиды, а идея есть? или тут только сборы проходят?)

Comment: @Gorets Кастинг)

Comment: да я вижу, кто выше руку тянет - тот в деле =)

Comment: идеи есть, также принимаются готовые на улучшение и работу. Надо б действительно какой-нибудь чат онлайн создать или группу дискуссионную. Джаббер-комнату можно создать. Пробуем заходить сюда - android-devs@conference.jabber.ru

Comment: имхо, скайп актуальнее

Comment: создавайте. Присоединимся в скайпе! Инициатива наказуема:)

Comment: чет жаббер комната не работает

Comment: Пробуйте еще. Видимо что-то не так делаете. Люди уже зашли:)

Comment: Пробую, комната оффланй, зашел в скайп

Comment: По-моему всё андроид-сообщество (именно разработчиков, и именно русскоязычное) сидит на этом форуме :)

Comment: Сомнительно! Здесь не сидит даже четверть людей, которые сидят на том же Хабре. Но Хабр не узкоспециализированный ресурс. Хоть я его и обожаю, но информации там слишком много:)

Comment: а про стековерфлоу некто и не слышал =)

Comment: это всё-таки англоязычный форум, хотя мои вопросы(с кривым английским) все равно понимают и даже отвечают на них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет! Я постоянно думаю над этим. С удовольствием бы поучаствовал в проекте (для души - так как работа есть). Опыт - год фриланса, своё собственное приложение в маркете 10к+ загрузок + полгода работы в офисе. Лично я не гарантирую даже и 10 часов в неделю, но всё равно поучаствовать хочется.

Давайте создадим гугл док или wave или что-то подобное для обсуждения.

П.С. моё почтение Виталию. Пользовался его гайдом по списку с иконками ;)

Answer (score 1):

Поучаствовал бы с удовольствием, очень интересуюсь разработкой под андроид. Веду свой блог по разработке под данную ось - [вот ссылка](http://dajver.blogspot.com/). Опыта мало, всего 2 месяца, но легко обучаем :)

Comment: Блог в мемориз) Мне как абсолютному начинающему есть что почитать)

Comment: :) рад что принес какую-то пользу.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то пока нет желающих.
Мне потенциально было бы интересно сотрудничество

Comment: О сотрудничестве можно писать на почту - alexfromakb@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

С удовольствием поучаствовал бы в OpenSource чтобы развивать немного навыки в этой области.

Имею опыт Java, один небольшой проект на Андроид коммерческий, скорее всего где-то на маркете он валяется. Но полное отсутствие времени, поэтому все на чистом энтузиазме.

Что вы подразумеваете под "Аутсорс". Если нужны люди -> обсуждаемо.

Comment: Аутсорс - работа с клиентами. Есть клиент, у него есть заказ:) Думаю дальше понятно.